# terminal not overwriting .class files

Tags: java, terminal, .class-file

I am taking a java programming class right now and it is my first real programming experience (although i have done some programming before). for the class i have to use jEdit to write programs, and terminal to compile and run them (i have a mac, and programs that automatically compile, run, and debug programs are banned for educational purposes). things were going very well for me at first, but a few days ago, terminal stopped overwriting the .class files on my QuickSort program when i try to compile it. i change the code so that it will look completely different when it runs, but after i compile and run it, there is no change. however, if i delete the .class files before i recompile, the changes are implemented next time i run it. neither me nor my teacher have been able to find any info on this problem or how to fix it (the exact same thing did happen to a classmate of mine three days before it happened to me, and we are the only mac users in the class). if anyone knows what the problem is, how to fix it, or where i can find someone who does know how to fix it, i would really appreciate it. deleting five .class files every time i compile my program is a huge pain and has already led to some serious problems for me. thank you so much for all of your help!

*edit: i am running mac os x 10.8.5

Comment: Could you please at least list the commands you execute as well as provide a brief outline of the source (and/or target) directory?

Comment: Paragraphs... When you wish other people read something you write, better put some effort into making it easy for them to read it. Wall of text will turn away many potential answerer.

Comment: i use these commands. the RandomArray class is just a test class that creates a random array then calls the sorting program itself. compiling that class does compile all of the necessary classes (at least, it did before this problem showed up):        "cd desktop/programs/multisorter" and "javac RandomArray.java"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't smart enough about detecting which class files are out of date, so either manually tell it to recompile everything using `javac *.java` or use a build tool such as [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).

---

The reason the compiler doesn't recompile all of the classes is that it tries to be 'smart' and avoid unnecessary work by only recompiling files that changed. If a `.class` file is newer than the matching `.java` file, the source code hasn't changed since the previous compilation so the class isn't recompiled.

This can cause problems when there are multiple files with a chain of dependencies. Consider this simple example:

```
// file: A.java
public class A { public static void main(String[] args) { new B().run(); } }

// file: B.java
public class B { void run() { new C().run(); } }

// file: C.java
public class C { void run() { System.out.println("hello world"); } }
```

When `A` is compiled for the first time, the compiler sees that it references `B`, which in turn references `C`. All three are compiled and all is well.

If `B.java` is modified and `A` is recompiled, the compiler sees that `A` references `B` and since `B.java` is newer than `B.class` it is recompiled. It doesn't recompile `C` because `C.java` hasn't changed. All is still well.

But if `C.java` is modified and `A` is recompiled the compiler sees that `A` depends on `B`, but since `B.java` hasn't changed it is not recompiled. So the compiler never gets to `C` and doesn't recompile it even though `C.java` has changed.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have just made my life a lot easier!