# How overwrite .class file from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, maven, terminal

I have java class which has a main method and calls a bash script. What it does in se is generate a value. What I am trying to accomplish is inject this output in the java class itself. I have tried by using the sed command which basically replaces all keywords that match the regex with the proposed change.

I made sure Maven runs the class before the actual build happens. However, as you might already know, my changes do not stick. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20167957/terminal-not-overwriting-class-files) that Eclipse is trying to be smart and not build files that have not changed. However, the manual way of trigger a build 'javac' does not seem to make my changes permanent.

Any solution on how I can make the output of the bash command a static value in the java class?

Thanks in advance. You're help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you want to modify a `.class` file from a Bash script. Normally you'd just call the script from Java (if the value can change) or call Bash to modify the Java code (horrendous, but might be the only way in extremely rare cases). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You want to run a bash script and extract a specific value from its standard output. Is that right? If it is then the part about Maven and Eclipse and .class file and terminal is really confusing and superfluous.

Comment: Do you want to run a `Process` and grab it's `OutputStream` at run-time or at compile time? The former sounds reasonable, the later yields why?

Comment: The reason why I am trying to achieve this, is because I need to inject a revision number at buildtime. I cannot fetch the revision number during runtime because the server can be updated with a new version, however the number should not update. That is why I am generating the number at runtime. I understand though that this is somewhat superfluous. What would the best way be then? I was able to inject the number though. The problem was I was using the sed command without the storing the output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Eclipse is programmed to  check the class file from changes before execution then rebuild if it changes.
You should try execute it directly from command line (javac YourClass.java && java YourClass). Let's see if it works as you intended.